# Having a problem about java return statement**SOLVED

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, return

I create this method to create an receipt. I had to use return statement .There was different product in receipt and i want to get an output like this.

---

```
Apple - 200.0 x 100 = 20000

bANANA - 123.2 x 20 = 12452

Total 32452
```

---

How can i do it with return statement ? My arrays contains Product name, price and count. 
Im getting missing return statement error

```
public String receipt(){
    for(int v=0 ; v < prdct.length ; v++) {
        if (prdct[v] != null)
            kral++;
    }

    for(int a=0 ; a < kral ; a++) {
        if (a == prdct.length)
            return ("Total Due = " + totaldue);
        return (prdct[a] + " - " + prdctprc[a] + " x " + cnt[a] + " = " + (prdctprc[a] * cnt[a]));
    }
}
```

Comment: If your array is empty there is no return. And if you want the complete receipt as returned string you should build up the return-string inside your method (just concatenate all strings) and return the result at the end.

Comment: You should also not forget that a return-statement will stop the execution of the function and exits the loop instantly.

Comment: The title of your question suggests that it is already `SOLVED`. Please post an answer yourself and share how you solved it. So everyone can benefit :-)

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem with that way. Thanks

```
public String receipt(){
        String rcptString="";
        for(int v=0 ; v < prdct.length ; v++) {
            if (prdct[v] != null)
                kral++;
        }

         for(int a=0 ; a < kral ; a++) {



             rcptString += (prdct[a] + " - " + prdctprc[a] + " x " + cnt[a] + " = " + (prdctprc[a] * cnt[a])+"/n");
             if (a+1 == prdct.length)
                 rcptString += ("Total Due = " + totaldue);

         }return  rcptString;
        }
```